# Generated equivalence relation is minimal

Tags: category-theory

We work in a category with limits and colimits. A relation $R$ on an object $X$ is a mono $r:=\langle r_0,r_1\rangle :R\to X\times X$. We can take the generated equivalence relation by taking the coequalizer $q:X\to Q$ of $r_0$ and $r_1$, then take its kernel pair $e:=\langle e_0,e_1\rangle:E\to X\times X$.

It is easy to prove the relation is an equivalence relation (since it is a kernel) and contains $R$. But I spent a while and cannot prove it is minimal. That is, every equivalence relation on $X$ factors through $E$.

$E$ is a kernel so it is not obvious to me how to construct a map out of it.

Comment: You haven't defined equivalence relation in this setup, I tried Googling but couldn't find a relevant definition. I have made up my own definition but I think it would be good for you to say what you want

Comment: @FShrike Here it is: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence#:~:text=In%20category%20theory-,1.,of%20the%20ambient%20Euclidean%20space).

Comment: Ok nice. Happy to say my home cooked definition is equivalent to theirs. Annoyingly, this doesn't come up on the nLab "equivalence relation" page...

Comment: Are you working with any other assumptions on your category? E.g. that it is well powered? That it is a topos? ... I can prove what you want if we know $E$ is in fact the pullback of $X\rightrightarrows X/R$ but I'm not so sure if it is

Comment: I presume you mean that every equivalence relation on $X$ that contains $R$ factors through $E$?

Comment: @FShrike In a topos I believe everything is good. But the construction can be carried out in any category, so I would like to know if it would work in general.

Comment: @joriki Yes, this is exactly what I would like to prove.